# Find Duplicate records while uploading Excel file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, excel

I want to restrict duplicates while uploading the excel data and to inform the user that the particular cell in excel contains duplicate value which is already exist in Sql Database.

(Duplicates should be checked in Excel (EMP_ID) against SQL (EMPLOYEE_ID).If duplicate record is found, Message should display as:"User cannot upload the data to with duplicate values. Kindly remove the duplicate fields and re-upload."

Is this possible if any idea can anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import the data using [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) into a staging table, the compare values using a join against SQL and return the duplicates back to the user so that he can fix them and re-upload the file.